# ssh tunnel between two android devices

Tags: android, ssh

I want to create a ssh tunnel between two android devices for directing internet traffic from one device to another. I installed connectbot and proxydroid in one smartphone. I ask: is there a ssh server app for android that is right for me?
The second question: i have a ssh server with public ip. Can i create a ssh tunnel from each device to this server for redirecting traffic from one device to another? If yes, how can i make this using these apps (connectbot and proxydroid)? 
Thanks to everybody

Answer (score 0):

1. I like this [SSH Server App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.sshserver&hl=de).
2. I do not know which "traffic" you want to redirect, so I can not help you there.

Comment: I have to run a c-language program sniffing outgoing internet packages from one device and incoming internet packages to the other device (i want to know jitter information of packets in a viber call between the android devices). i will prove this app: i hope it works. :)

Comment: Ah, I did not even know viber uses ssh for their calls

Comment: no no, viber works fine without ssh.it was just an example. i want to connect directly these two devices to transmit these information(internet packages) using 3g, nat does not allow me to do it. That's the reason i want to create a ssh tunnel for android